# sqlite insert query not commited to database immediately

Tags: linux, qt, sqlite

I am using sqlite 3.7, linux 2.6.38, qt 4.8.4

My code as below:

```
DataManager::DataManager(QObject *parent, const QString& path) : QObject(parent){

    this->db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    this->db.setDatabaseName(path);
    this->db.open();
    this->execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
    this->execute("PRAGMA synchronous=OFF;");
}
void DataManager::execute(const QString& sql) throw(DataException){

    QSqlQuery query(db);
    query.prepare(sql);

    if(!query.exec()) THROWDATA("Could not execute \"" + sql + "\"(" + query.lastError().text()+")", query.lastError().number());

    qDebug() << "commit:" << query.isActive() << query.lastError();
    query.clear();
    qDebug() << "commit:" << query.isActive() << query.lastError();
}
```

When I execute

```
this-> execute("Insert into table values('0' , 'Name');
```

The code does not commit to database immediately after about 10 secs the code gets commited.

Please need suggestion.

Comment: _"The code does not commit to database immediately after about 10 secs the code gets commited."_ How do you know? How are you checking this? Do you have any open transactions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the following line

```
this->execute("PRAGMA synchronous=OFF;");
```

If you want to be extra sure, you can explicitly enable the synchronous mode (which is usually the default):

```
this->execute("PRAGMA synchronous=NORMAL;");
```

Comment: See my updated answer. Also, are you starting any transactions?

Comment: @reedneb sorry tried it, still doesn't work. I am not starting any transaction. After write to database i check by querying it , it shows and then i power off the machine. And the record does not commit to database. It remains in OS memory i guess.

Comment: Run this in a terminal: `sqlite3 '/path/to/test.sqlite' 'create table t(x); insert into t values(32)'` and then power off the machine. `/path/to/` should be the same directory that you use to store the db in your code. After you power the system back on, does the table `t` contain the value `32`?

Comment: No Sir t did not contain value 32.

Comment: So it is not a problem with you code. What kind of file system is the directory on?

Comment: I am using ext3 file system